# Is bar plot the right choice for my data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame (**dcity**):

```
City            Income_Group     Number_of_Neigbourhoods
Metropolis      High                7
Metropolis      Mid                 6
Metropolis      Low                 12
Central City    High                9
Central City    Mid                 14
Central City    Low                 18
Star City       High                2
Star City       Mid                 7
Star City       Low                 21
Gotham          High                9
Gotham          Mid                 11
Gotham          Low                 19
...
```

**City:** my data frame has about 100 different cities

**Income_Group:** only three types of income groups *High*, *Mid*, and *Low*

**Number_of_Neigbourhoods**: these are numeric values

I am using the following function to show my data

```
ggplot(dcity)+aes(Income_Group, stat="bin")+ geom_bar()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWbPz.png) <–Looks like this

Is this the right way to showcase my data, namely a barplot?

(If possible)Is there a way to integrate the name of the cities?
I tried this:

```
ggplot(dcity)+aes(Income_Group, fill= City,stat="bin")+ geom_bar()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWbPz.png) <–Looks like this

It spat out the same graph as before, but rainbow coloured with the names of the cities, not exactly useful.

Comment: This is off-topic here, but it's on-topic at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). I'm flagging the question to be migrated.

Comment: Also your two images are the same. I was editing the question to make them visible but couldn't since one is obviously the wrong link.